# NetworkManager disrupt LAN connection after system reboot

Tags: lan, networkmanager

Since several weeks ago, every time I reboot from Linux, LAN connection cannot be established. I cannot use LAN in Linux(Arch Linux), Windows(Windows 10), or even BIOS when trying to boot-up through network. However, if I shutdown the computer and boot up from cold, the LAN connection works again. After some trial and error, I realized that if I disable `NetworkManager` by

```
systemctl disable NetworkManager
```

and enable `systemd-networkd` and `systemd-networkd` as instructed in [Archlinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-networkd) to connect, the problem is solved. LAN works perfectly after reboot. Yet once I enable NetworkManager again, the problem returns. So I think I can safely assume the problem comes from NetworkManager some how. Yet I am unable to identify the source of the issue. How do I debug the issue to find the exact cause so that the `NetworkManager` can work for me again?

Comment: If the problem continues to exist when you "boot other systems", how do you figure Network Manager from Windows is affecting the other OS?  If it is acting up between multiple OSs, then it sounds more like a faulty NIC to me.  have you tried a replacement (known-good) NIC to see if the problem persists?

Comment: I don't know if it's a hardware problem. It's a laptop so if possible I'd like to avoid replace parts unnecessarily. On the other hand, if hardware is faulty, the problem won't go away by merely `systemctl disable NetworkManager`, right? If NM is disabled, the weird reboot leading to dead LAN problem simply disappeared.